# Developer Tools Access not prompting after Xcode compile

Tags: xcode, macos

A friend recently gave me source code for an app he used to develop (he no long plans to support the app). In the last compiled version from him, when I run the application I get a prompt saying:

Developer Tools Access is trying to take control of another process. Type your password to allow this.

When I build the source and execute the app, I do not get the prompt and subsequently, the app does not work. It will not update what it should.

Is there a build setting I am missing in Xcode?  I have the same code signing cert as him, yet I don't get the Developer Tools Access prompt to give my compiled version permissions to "Take Control."

Comment: You should get this prompt exactly one time. The non-working app is most likely not related to this prompt.

Comment: Correct, I get this prompt once using the working version, until I reboot. I do not ever get the prompt on the non-working version...